# Stop Scheduler Job - Exit Point in PL/SQL Block

Tags: oracle, plsql, jobs, job-scheduling

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
    job_name => 'MYJOB', 
    job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
    job_action => <see below>
);

DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE (
    name => 'MYJOB'
);

-- pl/SQL block for the job:

BEGIN
    -- 1
    UPDATE ...
    COMMIT;

    FOR x IN (SELECT ...
    LOOP
        -- 2
        UPDATE ...
        COMMIT;
    END LOOP;

    -- 3
    UPDATE ...
    COMMIT;
END
```

When I execute

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.STOP_JOB (
    job_name => 'MYJOB', 
    force => FALSE
);
```

is there a special rule in the scheduler for terminating PL/SQL blocks at a special point within the PL/SQL block? In the example above, is it possible that the DML at Point "3" is not executed?

Comment: The exit point is after the last line.

Comment: The dbms_scheduler's job gets created and enabled - thus ran. If your Pl/SQL block is still executing, then you'll be able to stop the job, otherwise it will just finish. Check the force option of the stop_job procedure, because it requires a privilege, which will actually kinda "kill" the job. The default for this is force => false, which uses an interrupt mechanism.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I think Toru wants to know where does it actually exit the code, when you issue stop_job. Which, if used with force option or not, either kills the slave process or stops it gracefully.

Comment: Always hard to prove a negative, but I am pretty sure DBMS_SCHEDULER has no special abilities and an interrupt will be the same as a Control-C on the command line, i.e. it will be actioned if and when the PL/SQL runtime engine feels like it.

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `DBMS_SCHEDULER.STOP_JOB ()` with `force` set to false. According to the documentation this means it will try to "gracefully stop the job using an interrupt mechanism". There's no detail regarding this "interrupt mechanism" and sites on the interwebs simply regurgitate the  documentation without any further insights.

Let's see what happens. Here is a procedure which mimics yours. When it runs to completion there will be thirty-two records in T42.

```
create or replace procedure p_job_tst is
    n simple_integer := 1;
begin
    delete from t42;
    insert into t42 (stage, id) values (1, n);
    commit;
    for i in 1..30 loop
        n := n+1;
        insert into t42 (stage, id) values (2, n);
        commit;
        dbms_lock.sleep(2);
    end loop;   
    n := n+1;
    insert into t42 (stage, id) values (3, n);
    commit;
end;
/
```

The calls to `dbms_lock.sleep()` means it executes for a minute, which allow us to kill the job in mid-run without having to be super-fast with the typing. Here is the job:

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
       job_name             => 'apc.my_job1',
       job_type             => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
       job_action           => 'BEGIN p_job_tst; END;',
       start_date           => systimestamp + interval '10' second,
       repeat_interval      => 'FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=3',
       enabled              =>  TRUE,
       comments             => 'StackOverflow Test');
END;
/
```

Having started the job let's wait until it's running, then stop it:

```
SQL> select job_name, state, run_count from dba_scheduler_jobs where job_name = 'MY_JOB1';

JOB_NAME                       STATE            RUN_COUNT
------------------------------ --------------- ----------
MY_JOB1                        SCHEDULED                2

SQL> select job_name, state, run_count from dba_scheduler_jobs where job_name = 'MY_JOB1';

JOB_NAME                       STATE            RUN_COUNT
------------------------------ --------------- ----------
MY_JOB1                        RUNNING                  2

SQL> exec sys.dbms_scheduler.STOP_JOB(job_name=>'apc.my_job1', force=>false);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select job_name, state, run_count from dba_scheduler_jobs where job_name = 'MY_JOB1';

JOB_NAME                       STATE            RUN_COUNT
------------------------------ --------------- ----------
MY_JOB1                        SCHEDULED                3

SQL>
```

Before I stopped the job T42 had ten records. The current contents of T42?

```
SQL> r
  1* select * from t42 order by stage, id

        ID      STAGE
---------- ----------
         1          1
         2          2
         3          2
         4          2
         5          2
         6          2
         7          2
         8          2
         9          2
        10          2
        11          2

        ID      STAGE
---------- ----------
        12          2

12 rows selected.

SQL>
```

So the job was stopped gracefully but not at the end of the procedure. It seems as if the interrupt mechanism looks for a neat breakpoint with no locks or long running processes. Like your code my code has loads of such breakpoints. Each `commit` ends a transaction and frees any locks.

Which is good from the scheduler's point of view because it seems easy to stop your job "gracefully". Of course from an application perspective it's a complete nightmare. The job will ABEND in **an unknown state**. Some portion of the work will have been done and committed, and some portion will have been lost. There's no easy way to tell which how much of each, and in the meantime your database will be in a potentially inconsistent state.

There is best practice related to the issuing of `commit` statements: `commit` once, at the end of the Unit Of Work. A background job is a Unit Of Work, so it should have precisely one `commit` statement, right before the terminating `end` (assuming your block doesn't have an exception handler section, which it should).

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd check to see if your update in a loop [i.e. row-at-a-time = slow-at-a-time] could be re-coded to be a set based update.  After all, Oracle RDBMS is designed to be a very efficient set processing engine; a row-at-a-time solution will almost always under perform a set based solution and not be scalable.